# Adguardhome inside docker not resolving registered domain name to local IP address

Tags: linux, docker-compose, dns

I setup a DNS using adguardhome on a Ubuntu server in a docker container, I've added my domain name to adguardhome with its local ip address to the DNS rewrites, with a wild card *.domain.name, which starts with 10.x.x.x, my router is set to use that same IP address (primary) for its DHCP clients, along with Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 (secondary).  I've check my DHCP settings from a different machine running Windows 10, however, when I ping the domain name I'm getting an external IP address instead of the local IP address, when I tracert the domain name I'm getting my router's IP address as the first hop and the rest are all external from my ISP, can someone help me understand why I'm not getting the local IP address in the ping response and what to do to fix it?

Docker container settings:

```
services:
  adguardhome:
    container_name: adguardhome
    image: adguard/adguardhome:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    ports:
      - 53:53/tcp
      - 53:53/udp
      - 8081:80/tcp
    volumes:
      - /somepath/adguardhome/work:/opt/adguardhome/work
      - /somepath/adguardhome/conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf
    restart: unless-stopped
```

AdGuardHome:
[image: AdguardHome DNS Rewrites]